# trapping CTRL+C in shell into pipe

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script (`example.sh`) in which I am creating and allocating (mounting) space in the `/media` directory and I'm copying some files there for faster processing.

```
ram_disk=/media/ram_disk
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=100000000 tmpfs "$ram_disk"
sudo cp "$some_random_file" "$ram_disk"
```

At the end of this shell script, I unmount and delete `$ram_disk` as follows-

```
sudo umount "$ram_disk"
cd /media
sudo rm -r "$ram_disk"
```

So that `CTRL+C` interruptions doesn't create problems, I've added a `trap` handler at the start (first lines) of the shell script

```
ctrlc_count=0

    function no_sigint {
    
        let ctrlc_count++
        if [[ $ctrlc_count == 1 ]]; then
            echo "Aborting process"
            if [ -d "$ram_disk" ]; then
            sudo umount "$ram_disk"
            cd /media
            sudo rm -r "$ram_disk"
            else
            :
            fi
        fi
    
    }
    
    trap no_sigint SIGINT
```

And if no `SIGINT` is supplied, variable `ctrlc_count` remains `0` and `ram_disk` is removed normally at the end of the shell script (last lines)-

```
if [[ $ctrlc_count == 0 ]]; then
      sudo umount "$ram_disk"
      cd /media
      sudo rm -r "$ram_disk"
fi
```

This has been working fine so far. However, if I pipe the shell script with another bash command and supply `SIGINT`, the trap handler does not work -

```
bash example.sh | head -10
bash example.sh | tail -10
```

Using `CTRL+C` in the above scenario does not remove `$ram_disk`.

Any suggestions on how can I improve my code to take piping commands into consideration? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trap `EXIT` instead of `SIGINT`.

SIGINT refers to an interrupt signal, generated by Ctrl-C by default.  That's not the only condition that can end a script.

`EXIT` commands will run when the script exits regardless of the reason - unless it's an uncatchable signal such as SIGKILL.

Answer (score 4):

Trapping `EXIT` is a good solution, but it doesn't explain the behavior you're seeing.

When you use `ctrl-C` to send SIGINT to the foreground process group, the `tail/head` gets terminated.  The SIGINT trap in the bash script is executed, but in bash `echo` is a builtin so the `echo "Aborting process"` generates a SIGPIPE to the script which is uncaught and the script immediately terminates.  Writing error messages/diagnostics to stderr isn't just a good idea, it saves your from this bug.  The "correct" solution is to trap EXIT, but a (potentially) easier approach is to use `echo 'Aborting process' >&2`.

Comment: You could also use `/bin/echo` in the trap and see how the behavior changes

Comment: thanks! that makes a lot of sense. What does `>&2` do in this case? And how is it different than `&>`?

Comment: The `>&2` redirect causes the output of the command to go to stderr.  `&>` redirects both stdout and stderr, but is a bashism which should not be used (IMO, it is a violation of the Posix standard and `cmd &> name` ought to be interpreted to execute cmd in the background, followed by a truncation of `name`).